# At the end of Wonder Woman 1984, what is the status of the MacGuffin?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, wonder-woman-1984

At the end of Wonder Woman 1984

> Maxwell Lord renounces his wish to *be* the Dreamstone.

Given that

> at the moment that Lord wished to become the Dreamstone it "disintegrated" into sand

and

> when we see others renounce their wish, the effect of the wish seems to reverse itself, the best example being the wall in Egypt disappearing and the moat/stream reappearing in its place,

is it possible that

> the Dreamstone "reformed" itself?

Comment: I realize this may not be answerable from the movie itself, so word-of-God style answers are fine of course.

Comment: [For those unfamiliar with a MacGuffin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacGuffin)

Comment: A DCEU film question should use the [[tag:dc]] and [[tag:dc-extended-universe]] tags on it alongside the main film tag. Make sure to add them next time!

Comment: It's in a large warehouse sitting on the Ark of the Covenant!

Comment: @SethMMorton: not sure that the Dreamstone is "insignificant, unimportant, or irrelevant in itself".

Comment: @Taladris Huh? To what do you refer?

Comment: @SethMMorton: the definition of McGuffin you linked

Comment: @Taladris Ok, that’s true, but I was more focusing on the “object ... that is necessary to the plot and motivation of the characters” part of that sentence, and also that a “MacGuffin is revealed in the first act and thereafter declines in importance. It can reappear at the climax of the story but may actually be forgotten by the end of the story”.